# how to arrange photoshop layers as rows and columns like a grid?

Tags: plugins, script, adobe-photoshop, layout, grid

I have a bunch of images, all the same dimensions loaded onto different layers(1 image per layer) inside a psd.

I was wondering if there is any fast way to do this or any utility/script already written:
- take a number of rows/columns
- make the canvas fit all the images based on the rows/columns
- arrange the layers as rows and columns

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have all layers as separate files you can use Contact Sheet addon to arange them in rows/columns. It might even work with layers directly in the file, not sure.

You can find the addon on your install disk in Goodies folder, should also be available on Adobe's site (here's a link for windows version for CS4 http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4048&fileID=3767)